# Retrieving HTML code from website using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am doing a project in Android Studio where the app can retrieve the HTML code from a link and get the data in the HTML code. I tried using this code, but was unable to get an output. Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
val testingbox: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTexttest)
val url = URL("http://www.android.com/")
val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

try {
  val text = urlConnection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
  testingbox.setText(text)
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect()
}
```

Comment: testingbox.setText(text) replace to  testingbox.setText(Html.fromHtml(text))

Comment: Hi, I've tried as you have suggested. However, I have the fromHtml bit crossed through when I type it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Util class for scraping html code from any website.

**ContentScrapper.kt**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

object ContentScrapper {


    fun getHTMLData(activity: AppCompatActivity,url: String, scrapListener: ScrapListener) {
        Thread(Runnable {

            val google: URL?
            val `in`: BufferedReader?
            var input: String?
            val stringBuffer = StringBuffer()

            try {
                google = URL(url)
                `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(google.openStream()))
                while (true) {
                    if (`in`.readLine().also { input = it } == null)
                        break
                    stringBuffer.append(input)
                }
                `in`.close()

                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(stringBuffer.toString())
                }
            } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    scrapListener.onResponse(null)
                }
            }
        }).start()

    }


    interface ScrapListener {
        fun onResponse(html: String?)
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
ContentScrapper.getHTMLData(this,"http://google.com/",object : ContentScrapper.ScrapListener{
            override fun onResponse(html: String?) {
                if(html != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,html,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,"Not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Android Studio. Where do I put the util class?

Comment: Also, when I paste the code in I have the @SplashActivity in red. How do I resolve this?

Comment: you can add your activity name at the place of SplashActivity

Comment: Hi I've tried out the utility class, however I found that when I tried to search for a specific string of characters that I was looking for, it didn't exist in the HTML code. It is on screen when I open it on Google Chrome however. Is the code provided by the utility class different? Thanks.